# Cant Read $_POST values with $.post requests when formulating options with .each

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, .post

Formulated my options string using .each and sending it via .post to an external script.

```
        clicked.closest("form").find("input,textarea").each(function(){
            var input=$(this);
            if(index==1){
                options = "{"+input.attr("name")+":'"+input.val()+"'";
            }else if(index==no_inputs){
                options += ","+input.attr("name")+":'"+input.val()+"'}";
            }else{
                options += ","+input.attr("name")+":'"+input.val()+"'";
            }
            index++;
        });
        alert(options);
        $.post('../pages/ajax/add_orders.php',options,function(data){
            alert(data);
        });
```

..problem is when my php call script is..

```
    <?php
        print_r($_POST);
    ?>
```

I simply get an empty array with no values.

The first alert shows the formulated string correctly.

But the second one returns an empty value.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you trying to send the data as request parameters or request body

Comment: you could just try `$.post('../pages/ajax/add_orders.php', clicked.closest("form").serialize(), function (data) {
    alert(data);
});`

Comment: Don't build JSON manually!

Comment: Thanks Arun. Saved my day and thanks mike for that reminder. How stupid of me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're post needs to be an actual object, you're creating a string.

```
    clicked.closest("form").find("input,textarea").each(function(){
        var input=$(this);
        if(index==1){
            options[input.attr("name")] = input.val();
        }else if(index==no_inputs){
            options[input.attr("name")] = input.val();
        }else{
            options[input.attr("name")] = input.val();
        }
        index++;
    });
```

I think the above way will work.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead:

```
var options={};
clicked.closest("form").find("input,textarea").each(function(){
    var input=$(this);
    options[input.attr("name")] = input.val();
});
```